# Smale's proof on diffeomorphisms of 2-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

In the Smale's proof of *diffeomorphisms of 2-sphere* while proving the [Lemma 2](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/624c/80ee8684a4340c00ac99a208e8f78df538a4.pdf), he made a remark that **This is exactly the part of the proof of Theorem A which does not extend to the case of $S^n$.** I am unable to understand it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: He proved $Diff^+(S^2)\simeq SO(3)$, but there is a more general conjecture saying that $Diff^+(S^{n-1})\simeq SO(n)$. And the thing is that that proof lemma 2 doesn't hold for all $n$.

Comment: @Javi It is known that this homotopy equivalence does not hold in general in higher dimensions (I’ll say $n\geq 7$) due to the existence of exotic spheres. Namely any sphere can be obtained by gluing two $n$-disks by an (orientation preserving) diffeomorphism of $S^{n-1}$, and if two diffeomorphisms are isotopic (which would the case if $Diff_+(S^{n-1})$ is homotopy equivalent to the connected space $SO(n)$), then the resulting spheres are diffeomorphic.

Comment: @Alexsandar I believe that is known for all $n \geq 5$; there is a difference at either $\pi_0$ or $\pi_1$. Of course, it is due to Hatcher when $n=3$ and a major open question when $n=4$.